# 5V I/O Chip Which Works Like An Atmel µC Port?

Tags: microprocessor, atmel, port, vintage

I'm working on a project with a 5V vintage 8-bit microprocessor, which I would like to hook some I/O to.  I'd like to find a nice little package that could help me with this.  I'm happy if it is a modern chip.

It would need:

- Per pin input / output selection
- Input pull-up resistors built in and selectable
- Output capable of driving at least 50ma

Does such a chip exist?

Comment: 50mA drive in a GPIO chip? Good luck with that.

Comment: I could add transistors if needed... how about the other features?

Comment: The other ones are easy. The MCP23017/23S17 should have those.

Comment: Which 'vintage' MPU are you using?

Comment: @BruceAbbott 6502 family

Comment: Then you don't want a modern chip. They all use fancy protocols like I2C and SPI.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It doesn't need to be modern, but available of course. :)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It wouldn't be hard to bit-bang SPI using the data bus. That's what the NES and SNES did with their controllers. Though a parallel interface may be more in the spirit of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a memory-mapped peripheral into a 5V CPLD reasonably easily.

I was going to suggest the XC95 series, but Element14 and Digikey are showing no availability for 5V parts.  They do have a reasonable range of 5V CPLD's from other vendors.

If you're not familiar with Complex Programmable Logic Devices, they're the little brother to the FPGA.  They have a very different internal architecture to FPGA's, they tend to have a lot less capacity, and they usually store their configuration in internal EEPROM or similar instead of in an external Flash.

Comment: I've read about CPLDs but never used one.  Would they have the selectable pull-up feature?

Comment: @SamWashburn That would be heavily vendor- and device-dependent. It's been years since I used an XC95 or XC2S part (Xilinx CPLD's); I don't even remember if they offered selectable pullups. Some FPGA's certainly do, so it's quite possible. You'd need to do some sniffing around in datasheets.

Comment: @SamWashburn Have a look at [http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0776.pdf](page 5 of this Atmel CPLD datasheet) re the input keeper; I know it's not a pullup, but does it meet your actual requirement?

Comment: @SamWashburn Another option is to use two CPLD pins for each GPIO pin; one pin is the actual GPIO, and the other switches o/c or Vcc onto the other end of a resistor connected between the two pins.

Comment: I don't think the input keeper would work.  But the dual pins would be a solution, true.

Comment: The dual pins is a great idea, actually.  I'm beginning to think I can do this with 7400 logic.